# Pandas reading data from clickhouse returning error 'Unsupported object'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, clickhouse

when i'm using pandas to read data from clickhouse, it returns error:

```
raise Exception("Unsupported object {}".format(item))
Exception: Unsupported object [1,2,3,4]
```

the code is similar like this:

```
userID = [1,2,3,4]
df = pd.read_sql_query(
"select id, amount, ds from t_order where id in %(userID)s", ck_engine, params={'userID':userID})
```

it works fine in MySQL. Not sure what's going on in clickhouse.
could someone help me? THX.

Comment: could you provide the schema of the table *t_order*?

Comment: -- auto-generated definition
create table fact_paid_order
(
    order_id                 Int64,
    order_no                 String,
    one_id                   Int64,
    order_amount             Nullable(Int64),
    act_amount               Nullable(Int64),
    pay_time                 Nullable(String),
    ds                       String,
    ts                       String
)
    engine = MergeTree PARTITION BY ds
        PRIMARY KEY order_id
        ORDER BY (order_id, ds)
        SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192; thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue that you use the [sqlalchemy-clickhouse](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-clickhouse/) package - it is the old and unsupported package. This package doesn't support passing *list* to a query (see [escape_item](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse/blob/7a25e7467c3197f3ba5d3c5402cb1f27e9346bf1/connector.py#L54)-method).

To fix it:

- uninstall *sqlalchemy-clickhouse*
- install [clickhouse-sqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/clickhouse-sqlalchemy/).

*requirements.txt*

```
sqlalchemy
clickhouse-sqlalchemy
pandas
```

Comment: Hello! I am using `clickhouse-sqlalchemy` but I'm seeing the same error. Here are the package versions I'm using: `SQLAlchemy==1.4.49`, `clickhouse-sqlalchemy==0.2.4` and `pandas==2.0.3`, along with clickhouse latest version (23.8.2.7). Do you have any idea why this error persists? Well, in my case the column is an array.